# Python/HTTP - How does web browsers cache work?

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to create a (very minimalist) web server with Python using the `socket` module. 
I have a problem with, I think, web browser caching.

Explanation:
When I load a page, the first time work. It will work 2-3 other time at the beginning, then it will load just one time every two requests made by my browser (I use Firefox). I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, it works, I re-press <kbd>F5</kbd>, it loads nothing infinitely, I re-press <kbd>F5</kbd> and it works.
I looked at my python console, and it seems that Firefox doesn't send any request when the loading of the page fails. 
When I press <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>, it ALWAYS work, Firefox send a request each time and my webserver send it the page. 
I tried adding HTTP headers to prevent caching (Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires), but it still works one in two. I tested with Internet Explorer, and it works better, but it sometime fails (on 4-5 requests, it will fail only one time).

So, my question is:
Why Firefox and IE sometimes doesn't send request and still seems to wait for something? What is the web server supposed to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You don’t close the request sockets and you bind/close after every request. That doesn’t look good at all. Bind at start, close at the end and close every request socket after sending the data. Otherwise the browser will attempt to use an existing connection since you don’t say no to it. Also external code links will die at some point, always include the needed part of the code in the question.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can't believe I'm blind at this point. It solved the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about caching. You don’t close the sockets after sending a response nor do you tell the browser that you don’t support multiple requests. So the browser will assume it can request again with the same connection.

Close the connection and if you claim to support HTTP 1.1 add an appropriate Connection header.

Also don’t bind/close the server socket after each request. There’s no need and it will just make things not work. Bind on startup, close on shutdown.

The code might also fail on data that is non-ASCII since you tell the length of the *string* and not the actual data you send. These may be different.